# c++ native code DLL using an abstract class into a wrapper to be used in C# module

Tags: c#, c++, dll, wrapper

Hi i am having the same problem with abstract class.i am trying to wrap my cpp Dll calls to use in the C# module.

Dll is using the Factory pattern.which contain a class Factory,MiddileWare ,And their co**strong text**rresponding child class.Could any one help me to start the wrapper. i am stuck in between this.Your help will be appreciated. i am giving the flow here:

MiddleWareFactory.h

```
#pragma once
#include "MiddleWareConnection.h"
#include "std afx.h"

  #ifdef MIDDLEWAREFACTORY_EXPORTS
#define MIDDLEWAREFACTORY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
```

#define MIDDLEWAREFACTORY_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif

```
  MIDDLEWAREFACTORY_API enum eMiddleWareEngine
      {
          eRabitMQ = 0,  
          eZeroMQ,                           
          eActiveMQ          

        };
     // This class is exported from the MiddleWareFactory.dll

      class MIDDLEWAREFACTORY_API CMiddleWareFactory
      {
      public:
         CMiddleWareFactory(void);
         ~CMiddleWareFactory();
        // TODO: add your methods here.

        //Function to Create the  object of Broker module:implemnted the                   Factory   concept.
      BOOL CreateInstance(CMiddleWareConnection** pMObj);
     int m_eMomEngine;//To define which MOM need to enable.

};



extern MIDDLEWAREFACTORY_API int nMiddleWareFactory;

MIDDLEWAREFACTORY_API int fnMiddleWareFactory(void);
```

MiddleWareConnection.h

#pragma once

class CMiddleWareConnection
  {
   public:

```
  virtual ~CMiddleWareConnection(void)
  {
   }
  //Pure virtual fuctions for interfacing 
  virtual BOOL Connect(int nServerType)=0;
   virtual BOOL CreateSessionExchange() = 0;
   virtual BOOL CreateQueue(LPCTSTR lpszQueueName) = 0;
   virtual BOOL Disconnect() = 0;
   virtual BOOL Send(void *MomItem,LPCTSTR lpszKey, int               &nSendCount)=0;
   virtual BOOL Receive() = 0;
   virtual void StopReceiver() = 0;
   virtual void GetData(void* pMsg, int &nMsgLen,int nMsgType,int &nReceiveCount)=0;
   };
```

RabbitMQ.h

```
  #pragma once
  #include "MiddleWareConnection.h"
  #include "Amqp.h"
  #pragma comment(lib, "rabbitmq.4.lib")
  #define GET_DATA(a){memcpy(&a, pDataPtr,  sizeof(a));pDataPtr+=sizeof(a);}
  #define GET_DATA_EX(s,n){memcpy(s, pDataPtr, n);pDataPtr+=n;}

 typedef struct _ROUTINE_KEY
{
 CString RoutingKey;             

 }ROUTEKEY, *LPROUTEKEY;

   class CRabbitMQ :
   public CMiddleWareConnection
      {
          public:

      CRabbitMQ(CAppConfig &rConfig);
     ~CRabbitMQ();
      void   InitializeRBMQ(CAppConfig &rConfig);//Initialize RBMQ Config;
         BOOL   Connect(int nServerType);
         BOOL   Disconnect(void);
         BOOL   Send(void *MomItem, LPCTSTR lpszKey, int &nSendCount);
         BOOL   Receive(void);
         BOOL   CreateQueue(LPCTSTR lpszQueueName);
         BOOL   CreateSessionExchange();
         BOOL   BindQueue(LPCTSTR lpszQueue, LPCTSTR lpszExchangeName, LPCTSTR lpszKey);
         bool   IsConnected(){return m_bConnected;}
         void   SetKeyQueueCombination( TCHAR *pszQueueName, TCHAR *pszRoutingKey);
         void   StopReceiver();
         bool   ReEstablishRMQMWConnection();
        void   GetData(LPBYTE &pMsg, int &nMsgLen,int &nReceiveCount);
        void   GetData(void* pMsg, int &nMsgLen,int nMsgType,int &nReceiveCount);
     BOOL   GetNext_JasonListItem(LPJASON_ITEM pItem);
      LPRABBIT_MQ_ITEM GetNextItem();

      };
```

Here i want to expose the rabbitMq class functions[Connect,send,Recieve ete from MiddleWareConnection.h to C# module.

Thanks

Comment: The native dll only exports CMiddleWareFactory ?

Comment: CMiddilwareFactory.h & MiddlewareConnection.h

Comment: CMiddilwareFactory.h & MiddlewareConnection.h. And the export  calles are only in factory class.  MiddlewareConnection.h  contains  the pure virtual methods (i am inheriting the brokering classes  from this class)I have tested the dll from CPP module side, (by including the dll & both header diles)now i want  to  use it with C# Module also.

Comment: The cleanest way is to do a marshalling dll assembly, with a wrapping ref class. A ref class is a C++/CLI class which is visible from C# side. Tomorrow I will try to post an answer with a code example

Answer (score 0):

below I posted a small code example of a wrapping C++/CLI class. You could create a new C++/CLI project which links your native library and create a class following the example below. This will produce a managed assembly that you could reference from C# side. Hope it helps!

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vcclr.h>  

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

public ref class CMiddleWareConnection_Net
{
  public:

    CMiddleWareConnection_Net()
    {
        pMiddleWareConnection = NULL;
    }

    ~CMiddleWareConnection_Net()
    {
        //Release pMiddleWareConnection
        if (pMiddleWareConnection)
            delete pMiddleWareConnection;
    }

    void   InitializeRBMQ(CAppConfig_Net config)
    {
        // CAppConfig_Net is another ref class 
        // which provides a toNative method 
        // returning a plain C++ CAppConfig object
        CAppConfig rConfig = config.toNative();  

        pMiddleWareConnection = CRabbitMQ(rConfig);
    }

    bool   Connect(int nServerType)
    {
        return (pMiddleWareConnection->Connect(nServerType) == TRUE);
    }

    bool   Disconnect(void)
    {
        return (pMiddleWareConnection->Disconnect() == TRUE);
    }

    bool   Send(array<Byte>^ MomItem, String^ lpszKey, int% nSendCount)
    {
        //Assuming MomItem is a byte array...
        unsigned char *pData = new unsigned char[MomItem->Length];
        Marshal::Copy(MomItem, 0, IntPtr(pData), MomItem->Length);          

        //Marshal String^ to LPCSTR
        IntPtr ip = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(lpszKey);  
        LPCSTR str = static_cast<LPCSTR>(ip.ToPointer());

        bool bRet = (pMiddleWareConnection->Send(pData, str, nSendCount) == TRUE);

        //Freeing memory
        delete[] pData;
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ip);

        return bRet;
    }

    bool   Receive(void)
    {
        return (pMiddleWareConnection->Receive() == TRUE);
    }

    /* Other methods */
    ... 

  private:
    CMiddleWareConnection *pMiddleWareConnection;

};
```

Comment: Thank yo so much..i wil try with this one

Comment: Simon could you please give the steps to follow..i am bit confuse how to start..& where to use this code. "CAppConfig_Net" is another class?[which class is this?],what it is for?could you please give the overall outlook how can i use this  .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is another class which marshal CAppConfig. I wrote this way because CAppConfig is not posted.If you want post it.

Comment: MiddleWareFactory.h

Comment: @Fazna  I guess that in the new post `CppMathWrapper` is the ref class and `CppMath` the native C++ counterpart. If so the C# side is ok. But I don't understand the Wrapper part: what is oFact?

Comment: i tried one example with CPPMath class CLRWrapper::CppMathWrapper::CppMathWrapper()
{
   middleWareFactory *oFact;//  MiddleWareFactory.h pointer
    oFact->createInstance(&cppMath);'// here i want to pass the reference & wanna get back the child class type:now i am stuck here..how can we pass/marshal the object:im getting the error

} 
BOOL CLRWrapper::CppMathWrapper::connect(type)
{
  return (cppMath->Connect(nServerType) == TRUE);
}

..........And so On............

Comment: cppMath must be an object of a pure C++ class. Then, after having created it in the createInstance, you could marshal it into a new object of a C++/CLI class.

Comment: "Then, after having created it in the createInstance, you could marshal it into a new object of a C++/CLI class" how to do this marshal object?

Comment: In your post there isn't the code of `cCppMath`, it depends on it. Post the code or look at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22e4dash.aspx). It is a useful guide on how to marshal types from C++ to .Net

Comment: `CLRWrapper::CppMathWrapper::CppMathWrapper()
 {
  middlewareConnection *oConn;  
   middleWareFactory oFact= new middleWareFactory ();// how to marshal the object?? 
   oFact->createInstance(&oConn);'// here i want to pass the reference 

}`

Comment: I give up, I can't understand what you are doing. A cleaner post with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) could be of help

Answer (score 0):

****MiddleWareFactory.h****

```
     BOOL CreateInstance(CMiddleWareConnection** pMObj)
        { 
          //if( some config value)
            *pMObj = new RabbitMq();
          // esle
               /***other MOm like OBCS,OSCS etec...**/

        }
```

****MiddlewareConnection.h****

```
  have the basic abstract functions....

**Rabbitmq.h**

it is one of the child class.
```

****Wrapper****

```
CLRWrapper::CppMathWrapper::CppMathWrapper()
{
    cppMath = new cCppMath();
    oFact->createInstance(&cppMath);'// here i want to pass the reference & wanna get back the child class type:now i am stuck here..how can we pass/marshal the object:im getting the error

} 
BOOL CLRWrapper::CppMathWrapper::connect(type)
{
  return (cppMath->Connect(nServerType) == TRUE);
}

..........And so On............
```

> > CLR Wrapper.cpp(11) : error C2664: 'Factory::createInstance' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::interior_ptr' to 'Base **'
> >         1>        with
> >         1>        [
> >         1>            Type=cCppMath *
> >         1>        ]
> >         1>        Cannot convert a managed type to an unmanaged type
>
> ```
> }
> ```

instead of this we are using **createinstance()**[InitializeRBMQ() is inside connect(),so it will be handled inside i think]

```
void   InitializeRBMQ(CAppConfig_Net config)
    {
    // CAppConfig_Net is another ref class 
    // which provides a toNative method 
    // returning a plain C++ CAppConfig object
    CAppConfig rConfig = config.toNative();  

    pMiddleWareConnection = CRabbitMQ(rConfig);
}
```

C# side
    i want to expose :

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
CppMathWrapper wrapper = new CppMathWrapper();
wrapper.connect(0);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i tried one example with CPPMath class.In real i am attaching the code below:

```
CLRWrapper::CppMathWrapper::CppMathWrapper()
{
   middlewareConnection *oConn;// MiddleConnection.h pointer
   middleWareFactory oFact= new middleWareFactory ();//  MiddleWareFactory.h object
   oFact->createInstance(&oConn);'// here i want to pass the reference & wanna get back the child class type:now i am stuck here..how can we pass/marshal the object:im getting the error.How could i wrap the object....the same like 

}                                                                                                                                           
BOOL CLRWrapper::CppMathWrapper::connect(type)
{
  return (oConn->Connect(nServerType) == TRUE);
}

..........And so On............
```